# VBA Do While Loop

Tags: ms-access, vba

Good Morning,

I am building a database that will be used for scheduling employee work assignments.  Below is the code that I am using to create the actual daily work assignments.  The intent is that this will loop through each employee in the company and if they are in a work status it will also read their assigned schedule version.  Then if the employee is in a work status the db will list their work assignments for each day.

The issue that I am encountering is that this only reads the first employee in the table and gives every other employee the work assignments that the first employee should have.  Again, the intent is that the code will look at each employees, one at a time, and append the correct assignments to tbl_employee_work_assignments based on each employees status and schedule version.

Can someone help me understand how to do this correctly, please?

Many Thanks!!!

```
Private Sub btn_build_assignment_schedule_Click()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tbl_employees")

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM tbl_employee_work_assignments"

    Do While Not rs.EOF
                Dim X As String
                Dim Y As String
                X = employee_schedule_version.Value
                Y = employee_status.Value
                DoCmd.SetWarnings False
                DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM tbl_employee_work_assignments"
                Select Case True
                    Case X = 1 And Y = 1
                        db.Execute "qry_append_schedule_1"
                    Case X = 2 And Y = 1
                        db.Execute "qry_append_schedule_2"
                    Case X = 3 And Y = 1
                        db.Execute "qry_append_schedule_3"
                    Case X = 4 And Y = 1
                        db.Execute "qry_append_schedule_4"
                End Select
            rs.MoveNext
            Loop
    rs.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: `"DELETE * FROM tbl_employee_work_assignments"` deletes *all* work assignments from *all* employees. I'm quite sure you don't want that.

Comment: Thank You Tomalak.  I intentionally have the data deleted from the table each time that a schedule is built.  This allow us to evaluate different scenarios that we create.  One of our goals is to find scheduling practices that allow us to more efficiently use our resources.  That being said, would keeping this line of code cause the problem that I am trying to solve?

Comment: Although you are iterating over a recordset (`rs`), you don't seem to be referencing any data from the recordset - what does the recordset contain?

Comment: Lee Mac....Thank You for taking the time to respond.  The record set contains a list of employees.  The purpose of the code is to look at the list of employees, determine their work status and their schedule version and based on those two values, bring a set of predetermined assignments to be completed.  Please see above addition that I made to the code that I am using.  I was quite sure that I was only having an issue with the Do While Loop so that is all that I included.  I have now included all code.

Comment: As you're advised, you don't refer to the rs anywhere. `employee_schedule_version.Value` is refering to the form button is in. Try `X=rs.Fields("employee_schedule_version").Value` (Y is similar). Shouldn't "qry_append_schedule_1-4" know which employee they are working on (or do you refer to form field in query)?

Comment: It feels like your code relies on some magic to happen, that doesn't. Be sure to use [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), and please read and follow [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the *very* limited information provided and making a few assumptions, I would hazard a guess that your code should be changed to something along the lines of the following:

```
Private Sub btn_build_assignment_schedule_Click()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tbl_employees")

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM tbl_employee_work_assignments"

    With rs
        Do Until .EOF
            If !employee_status = "1" Then
                Select Case !employee_schedule_version
                    Case "1": db.Execute "qry_append_schedule_1"
                    Case "2": db.Execute "qry_append_schedule_2"
                    Case "3": db.Execute "qry_append_schedule_3"
                    Case "4": db.Execute "qry_append_schedule_4"
                End Select
            End If
            .MoveNext
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

This assumes that `employee_status` and `employee_schedule_version` are string-valued fields in your table `tbl_employees`.

Without knowing the structure of your table `tbl_employees` and the SQL behind your queries `qry_append_schedule_1`, `qry_append_schedule_2`, etc. it is difficult to advise.

Comment: @Saved You're most welcome, happy to help - not sure why my answer was downvoted.

Comment: Im not sure either.  I tried to up vote it and it will not let me.  The message box that popped up said that because I have less than 15 reputation points (new to the forum this month), my vote will be recorded but the publicly displayed Post Score will not change.  I give you my word that I tried to up vote...  But again, I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: Lee Mac....Could I trouble you for some help again, please?  I have found that when I added an second employee with Employee Schedule 1 ("qry_append_schedule_1") I ran into an issue that I again cannot remedy.  The first employee with Employee Schedule 1 was then given a second set of identical work assignments and the second employee with Employee Schedule 1 was given two sets of identical work assignments.  Can you help me understand how to correct this issue?

Comment: @Saved This should really be addressed as a separate question, in which you should include the SQL content of your append query ("qry_append_schedule_1") and an example of the content of any tables to which the query refers.